# Assert in python code & unit testing that checks if there is assert statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a code with an `assert` statement in it. Also, I'm doing unit testing on that code and I want to give a condition and if there is an `assert` statement in the code the test will pass.

```
def do_something(m, n):
   assert m !=0, "m has to be greater then 1"
       .....
```

In unit testing, I want to:

```
class Test_ (unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        # if m=0
        self.assert?????(m=0, ??not sure??)
```

What to write in order to test if there is an `assert` statement to `m=0`?
I saw something about context manager? Is it related?

Comment: `assert` statements are mostly for debugging and rough "sanity checks". You shouldn't need to unit test your `assert` statements. You should be unit testing whether your function works as you expect it to, meaning whether it returns the expected value or raises the expected exception on wrong input.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a unittest I'd remove the `assert` from the tested function and instead raise an exception.

Then you can test that in your unittest with [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

```
def do_something(m, n):
   if m <= 1:
       raise ValueError('m has to be greater than 1')

class Test_(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            do_something(0, 'whatever')
```

Comment: I tried it and it ends up well! test was ok. Thank you! I was very confused with all assert/assertion/exception...

Answer (score 0):

I mostly agree with @DeepSpace, but if you want to keep using `assert`, you can test that your function raises `AssertionError` in the conditions you expect.

```
def do_something(m, n):
    assert m != 0, "m has to be greater than 1"


class TestDoSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_raises_for_zero(self):
        with self.assertRaises(AssertionError):
            do_something(0, 'whatever')

    def test_raises_for_negative(self):
        with self.assertRaises(AssertionError):
            do_something(-1, 'whatever')
```

And, to expand on your question about context managers. In our examples we use a context manager when we invoke `self.assertRaises` in the `with` statements. Context managers are helpful when we temporarily want to change how something works or looks, in this example the context manager helps us catch an exception and make sure that it is raised when we call `do_something` with certain arguments.

Comment: What is the difference between ->  assert m != 0, "m has to be greater than 1" and  -> raise ValueError('m has to be greater than 1').  and which one is cleaner?

Comment: I tried @antonagestam's answer too and the code runs faster? could be related?

Comment: @Racheli It's good to be aware of that some runtime optimization flags strip assertions from code. Some argue that assertions should only be used in tests and not in production code. I've written code in both styles and both definitely work, but I think raising a `ValueError` is usually somewhat more semantically meaningful. When I see a `ValueError` raised from a function I instantly know something was wrong with its input data.

Comment: I've found Python's document about how to you assertion effectively: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively